Powerapps Incorporate repeated instructions into a loop
Based on instruction from the 4 ValTeams, I have this code to give instructions to the DP Teams.  There are 16 DP teams.  As you can see, I've written several instructions for each DP Team.  Is there a way to put them into a loop?
{
UpdateContext({OneCRMDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam2",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam1",OneCRM) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({GiftAidDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam1",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam1",GiftAid) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({BHFLotteryDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam3",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam1",LotteryStarVale) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({EmailMarketingDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam4",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam1",EmailMarketing) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({FinalDecision: Concatenate( OneCRMDecision,GiftAidDecision,LotteryDecision, EmailMarketingDecision)});
If (Find("S",FinalDecision)>0,UpdateContext({FinalInstructionValue:"Suppress"}),
UpdateContext({FinalInstructionValue:"Delete"})
);
Patch(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam1"),{FinalInstruction : FinalInstructionValue});
//Digital Sitecore instructions
UpdateContext({OneCRMDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam2",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam2",OneCRM) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({GiftAidDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam1",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam2",GiftAid) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({BHFLotteryDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam3",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam2",LotteryStarVale) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({EmailMarketingDecision:
If (LookUp(colValidationReqs,TeamName="ValTeam4",ValidationResult) = "Delete" ,"D",
If (LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam2",EmailMarketing) = "S","S","D"))
});
UpdateContext({FinalDecision: Concatenate( OneCRMDecision,GiftAidDecision,LotteryDecision, EmailMarketingDecision)});
If (Find("S",FinalDecision)>0,UpdateContext({FinalInstructionValue:"Suppress"}),
UpdateContext({FinalInstructionValue:"Delete"})
);
Patch(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,LookUp(colValidationDPRepsInstructions3,Team="DPTeam2"),{FinalInstruction : FinalInstructionValue});}
